# Can someone identify this mushroom?

Tags: botany, species-identification, mushroom

I found this monster on my lawn in New Hampshire USA, with a pileus that measures about 8.5 inches across. My mother has threatened to eat it unless I can demonstrate that it's poisonous, so any help identifying it would be greatly appreciated. I should mention that the mushroom is a slightly richer more brown than the fluorescent lighting suggests.

My best guess so far is an armillaria of sorts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: I doubt it is an armillaria. They usually grow in groups at the trees or dead strunks and have a darker centre. But being  European, I am unfamilair with American species. Depending how fond you are of your mother, I would strongly advise against eating an unidentified mushroom.

Comment: Do not eat any mushroom unless it is fully identified.  The results of a mistake can easily be fatal.

Comment: mgkrebbs is absolutely right. Some more information that might help with the ID is details of substrate it was growing on (or an in situ photo) and a spore print. That _may_ be enough for an expert to ID it.

Comment: It is so big and beautiful

Comment: @mgkrebbs And even photographic evidence is an *'inderect'* evidence and could be insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a member of the genus [Amanita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita), judging by the vellum traces on the cap, remains of a ring (2nd photo, under your thumb), free white gills.

What we are missing for a better id is the base: is there a volva, a bulbous end...? Please dig out your mushrooms instead of cutting them off.

Also, the colour is significant: are there pinkish tinges (-> A. rubescens?) or is it just brown?

Comment: Good shout. It think it looks a lot like *Amanita porphyria*

Comment: I don't recall any pinkish tinges. In any case since I haven't given enough information for an exact id, and the general consensus that it is most likely an Amanita, I will accept this as an answer. Thank you!